# How to delete any other fields than the specified ones in javascript object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a js object like this

```
{
    "firstName": "percy",
    "lastName": "jackson",
    "languages":["Node", "english"],
    "country": "Canada"
}
```

the acceptable fields are: `firstName, lastName, languages, country`

If I get object like this:

```
{
    "firstName": "percy",
    "lastName": "jackson",
    "email":"percy.jackson@gmail.com",
    "languages":["Node", "english"],
    "phoneNumber": "872612334",
    "dob": "04/06/1990",
    "countryCode": "+21",
    "country": "Canada"
}
```

`I want to truncate all the extra fields which are not acceptable`, how do I do this, deleting them manually one by one is not allowed(since everytime we might not have the same set of extra fields), though `only aim is to keep the acceptable fields.`

Comment: You can use `map()` to create a new array that only has the allowed properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the acceptable keys in an array, and then loop over the object keys removing the ones that don't match. Note, that this method mutates the object, rather than creating a new one.

```js
const ok = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'languages', 'country'];

const obj = {
    "firstName": "percy",
    "lastName": "jackson",
    "email":"percy.jackson@gmail.com",
    "languages":["Node", "english"],
    "phoneNumber": "8726905758",
    "dob": "04/06/1990",
    "countryCode": "+21",
    "country": "Canada"
}

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  if (!ok.includes(key)) delete obj[key];
});

console.log(obj);
```

Additional documentation

- [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Answer (score 4):

Just create a new object and add only the required properties.

using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const obj = {
  firstName: "percy",
  lastName: "jackson",
  email: "percy.jackson@gmail.com",
  languages: ["Node", "english"],
  phoneNumber: "872612334",
  dob: "04/06/1990",
  countryCode: "+21",
  country: "Canada",
};

const acceptableFields = ["firstName", "lastName", "languages", "country"];

const result = acceptableFields.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr] = obj[curr];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

You can also use [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop

```js
const obj = {
  firstName: "percy",
  lastName: "jackson",
  email: "percy.jackson@gmail.com",
  languages: ["Node", "english"],
  phoneNumber: "8726905758",
  dob: "04/06/1990",
  countryCode: "+21",
  country: "Canada",
};

const acceptableFields = ["firstName", "lastName", "languages", "country"];

const result = {};
for (let prop of acceptableFields) {
  result[prop] = obj[prop];
}

console.log(result);
```

**UPDATED CODE:** If acceptable fields are not there in obj.

```js
const obj = {
  email: "12345@gmail.com",
  lastName: "Harshi",
  name: "ivmla",
  siranme: "arris",
  password: "2484489",
  dob: "05/12/1980"
};

const acceptableFields = ["firstName", "lastName", "languages", "country"];

const result = {};
for (let prop of acceptableFields) {
  if (obj[prop]) result[prop] = obj[prop];
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: These methods turn the unacceptable fields to 'undefined'

Comment: @Vinita Serioursly where? How that possible?

Comment: @Vinita Please check how you've used the code. I mean It's not possible. I'm not modifying the original array `acceptableFields ` or original object `obj`

Comment: how do I attach a screenshot here?

Comment: Just add in your question and after a minute remove it

Comment: You can also use `codesandbox` and copy/paste the code and I'll check it there.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-aryabhata-d9s8x?file=/src/index.js

Comment: There is no code similar to this question. on codesandbox

Comment: I said acceptable fields and not must fields, your code is treating the acceptable fields as compulsory. You can check the link I have shown the example.

Comment: @Vinita Code is not there. I've checked it twice...

Comment: check once more please, I forgot to save it :|

Comment: @Vinita That was because there were not acceptable properties in obj. code updated . https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-bouman-n7mcv?file=/src/index.js:830-1177

Comment: Is that what you want ?

Comment: You just need to check if there value exist in obj or not. If it does then add in the result object.

Comment: yes, I understood the problem, thanks for the effort :)

Comment: Glad I could help 

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a [for...in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). For instance:

```js
const obj = {
  "firstName": "percy",
  "lastName": "jackson",
  "email": "percy.jackson@gmail.com",
  "languages": ["Node", "english"],
  "phoneNumber": "8726905758",
  "dob": "04/06/1990",
  "countryCode": "+21",
  "country": "Canada"
};

const alw = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'languages', 'country'];

for (let p in obj) alw.includes(p) || delete obj[p];

console.log(obj);
```